# Possible to auto-expand Google Compute Engine disks?

Tags: database, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a RethinkDB cluster in [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), with pd-ssd disks attached. I am wondering however, if the disks can be auto-expanded in order to not run out of space?

Comment: There're a script exactly for this: http://terrenceryan.com/blog/index.php/autoresizing-persistent-disks-in-compute-engine/

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Thanks! Wanna write an answer detailing this?

Comment: i'm not sure i have rights to do this :) it will be basically copy-paste from this blog, which is not mine. but link in the comment will work for other people, if they will find this question

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Well, the code is Apache License, so if you post the full code with license intact it shouldn't be a problem at all: https://github.com/tpryan/SharedCode/blob/master/BlogPosts/2016/04/Autoscale%20Disk/autoscale-disk. Also, if you attribute the original blog post I don't think anyone would have a problem with it?